# Android crop image not working android-crop

Tags: android, image, crop, onactivityresult

I am using library https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop and not being able to get the cropped image i dont know why below is some code that i am following from documentation

```
_Profile_Image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE_FROM_GALARY);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_FROM_GALARY) {

            beginCrop(result.getData());
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_PICK && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        beginCrop(result.getData());
    } else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP) {
        handleCrop(resultCode, result);
    }
}

private void beginCrop(Uri source) {
    Uri outputUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(), "cropped"));
    new Crop(source).output(outputUri).asSquare().start(getActivity());
}

private void handleCrop(int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        _Profile_Image.setImageURI(Crop.getOutput(result));
    } else if (resultCode == Crop.RESULT_ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Crop.getError(result).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

i am able to open the corp activity and it also crops the image and showing saving picture, but the problem is that after cropping image it is not coming in onActivityResult so that i can handle the crop image. 
**I Dont know what i am doing wrong in the code , I am just following the documentation**

Help will be Appreciated Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to visit the https://github.com/snowdream/awesome-android and especially give a try for https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

Comment: where is requestcode when you start Crop Activity?

Comment: checkout [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) library.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class ImageResizer {

 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String filename,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);
    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);
}




public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (calculate_sample_size)
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }

        // This offers some additional logic in case the image has a strange
        // aspect ratio. For example, a panorama may have a much larger
        // width than height. In these cases the total pixels might still
        // end up being too large to fit comfortably in memory, so we should
        // be more aggressive with sample down the image (=larger inSampleSize).

        long totalPixels = width * height / inSampleSize;

        // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels we'll sample down further
        final long totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

        while (totalPixels > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
            totalPixels /= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
    // END_INCLUDE (calculate_sample_size)
}
}
```

**Hope this help :)**